# WPF - play default windows sound when TextBox cannot recieve any more input

Tags: wpf, textbox, audio

I'd like the default windows system sound to play when a user attempts to enter text into a WPF TextBox which has already reached it's MaxLength value.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not used to sound playing in WPF, but I suggest you to suscribe to the KeyDown event of your textbox, and test the number of characters in the textbox against its maximal capacity.